# Mac OSX custom screen saver

Tags: objective-c, macos, catextlayer

How exactly can text be added to a custom screen saver, using a CATextLayer?

I'm trying to display a string of text drawn on a CATextLayer as part of a screen saver.

```
- (void) startAnimation
{
    [super startAnimation];

    _textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    _textLayer.string = @"Test.";
    _textLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    _textLayer.foregroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;

    [self.layer addSublayer:_textLayer];
}
```

(`_textLayer` is defined as an instance variable)

I've provided my attempt above, trying to create a CATextLayer, then add it to the screen saver layer...to no avail. When I build, then install the screen saver, nothing shows up.

I've looked around online, but couldn't find an example of a CATextLayer being used in the context of a screensaver.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/90488/calayer-in-ios-with-swift-10-examples

The site above walks through using a CATextLayer, but not specifically in the context of a screen saver.

Comment: https://github.com/packagesdev?tab=repositories enjoy :)

Comment: What's `self.layer`?

Comment: `self` is an instance of `ScreenSaverView` which is a subclass of `NSView`. So isn't `self.layer` the NSViews layer property? @JoshCaswell

Comment: Thanks @StefanS! Those are some really cool examples, do any of them render any kind of text?

Comment: Check s.sudre.free.fr

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Is it non-`nil`?

Comment: as a test set wantsLayer to true on your view layers to see if it's a core animation issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but for posterity's sake, you need to create a layer first that covers the screen, and assign it to the (screensaver)view. From then on you can add your CATextLayer or other layers.

```
        self.layer = CALayer()
        guard let layer = self.layer else {
            errorLog("\(self.description) Couldn't create CALayer")
            return
        }
        self.wantsLayer = true
        layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
        layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
        layer.frame = self.bounds
```

As someone who went that way, I would however highly, highly, recommend you consider using a NSTextView instead, it makes things so much simpler :

```
        // This is the debug view
        let debugTextView = NSTextView(frame: bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20))
        debugTextView.font = .labelFont(ofSize: 30)
        debugTextView.string += "Radar# FB7486243 (isPreview bug) : \(isPreviewBug) \n"
        
        self.addSubview(debugTextView)
```